# I only get last character when passing variable in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

When I use the following text in my .htaccess I only get the last character of the variable being sent.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_\-])+/$ home.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `+` in the grouping:

```
^([0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+)/$
```

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot. I'm pretty new to .htaccess so this was a big help to keep me moving. Thanks again.

Comment: One more question: What if I don't want the name 'account' to redirect to home.php because it's a folder with an index.php can I exclude that word from the redirect. Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewSomers add a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/account/` right above the `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Ahh Ok. Thanks. my work around was to remove the slash in rewrite and then include / in all my links..but this is much better.